# Android - Getting values from a notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-edittext

I can't find anything on this on google, nor here? But I am trying to create a notification and retrieve the value of an EditText field that has been set as a custom view for the notification

Is there anyway to retrieve this value? As notification's (as far as I'm aware) can just be set and/or updated.. but there must be some way!

Comment: what kind of notification is it.. dialog or something else..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. The actual `EditText` view inside your notification is not even owned by your process - it's instantiated by the system using the `RemoteViews` object you are providing. The only way of communicating with it is by sending back predefined intents, for example via `setOnClickPendingIntent`. You cannot retrieve a content of `EditText` that way, though.

As a solution I'd recommend to display a dialog or activity with your `EditText` when user taps the notification, and handle their input there.

Comment: I thought as much, I'll make a dialog instead. It would have just been handy as the app quickly asks the user a question, so to answer in the notification bar would be one or two less steps for the user to go through to answer a question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In your notification Intent

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, FlightActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("whatever",YOUR_STRING_VALUE);
notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

When the application starts, you can get it using the intent

Is this what you want?

Comment: but this intent is inside pending intent for notification. So this intent is created before the notification, so how can he modify it during the existence of notification?

Comment: But when he creates the pending intent he surely knows what will the notification display